# Positioning a cytoscape.js "loop" edge in the bottomright of a node, going counter clockwise

Tags: cytoscape.js

How can I set the styling of a cytoscape.js '[loop edge](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/loop-edges)' so that it rotates counterclockwise about the bottom right corner of a long (150px wide) rectangular node?

I have been fiddling with the style settings and just can't figure it out.  The best I can tell I should be able to tune these for styles to get what I want:

```
      selector: '.loop',
        style: {
          'loop-direction': '?deg',
          'loop-sweep': '?deg',
          'target-endpoint': '90deg',
          'source-endpoint': '105deg',
        }
      },
```

Which is something like this arrow, in red:

[image]

But I can't really get anything better than this snippet.  I just can't get the curve to "flip" to the other side.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    
    style: [{
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
          'width': 150,
          'shape': 'rectangle',
          'background-opacity': 0.5,
        }
      },

      {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
          'line-color': 'black',
          'target-arrow-color': 'black',
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
          'curve-style': 'bezier'
        }
      },
      {
        selector: '.loop',
        style: {
          'loop-direction': '90deg', 
          'loop-sweep': '-90deg',
          'target-endpoint': '90deg',
          'source-endpoint': '105deg',
        }
      },

    ],

    elements: {
      nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n16'
        }
      }],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          source: 'n16',
          target: 'n16'
        },
        classes: 'loop'
      }, ]
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#cy {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.15.1/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>cytoscape loop edge demo</h1>

  <div id="cy"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to get it to work by adding the `control-point-step-size` key and then fiddling with all the dials.  I wish there was a "debug" mode where I could see the control points and bezier stuff that these dials manipulate:

```
  'loop-direction': '100deg', 
  'loop-sweep': '-20deg',
  'target-endpoint': '90deg',  // Up is 0 deg, going clockwise. From center of node, where the edge ends (pointing back into the node. 
  'source-endpoint': '105deg',  // Up is 0 deg, going clockwise. From center of node, where the edge comes out of the node.  
  'control-point-step-size': 72,
```

[image]

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    
    style: [{
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
          'width': 150,
          'shape': 'rectangle',
          'background-opacity': 0.5,
        }
      },

      {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
          'line-color': 'black',
          'target-arrow-color': 'black',
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
          'curve-style': 'bezier'
        }
      },
      {
        selector: '.loop',
        style: {
          'loop-direction': '100deg', 
          'loop-sweep': '-20deg',
          'target-endpoint': '90deg',
          'source-endpoint': '105deg',
          'control-point-step-size': 72,
        }
      },

    ],

    elements: {
      nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n16'
        }
      }],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          source: 'n16',
          target: 'n16'
        },
        classes: 'loop'
      }, ]
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#cy {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.15.1/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>cytoscape loop edge demo</h1>

  <div id="cy"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is correct yet it seems Cytoscape will always default to clockwise loops when the endpoints are specified with angles (they are relative to the shape border!).

If you don't resort to "unbundled bezier-edges" where you can manually specify control points (and thus the curve of the edge) then using predefined values for endpoints might be good enough:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
    
    style: [{
        selector: 'node',
        style: {
          'width': 150,
          'shape': 'rectangle',
          'background-opacity': 0.5,
        }
      },

      {
        selector: 'edge',
        style: {
          'line-color': 'black',
          'target-arrow-color': 'black',
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
          'curve-style': 'bezier'
        }
      },
      {
        selector: '.loop',
        style: {
          'loop-direction': '90deg', 
          'loop-sweep': '-90deg',
          'target-endpoint': 'outside-to-line',
          'source-endpoint': 'outside-to-line',
        }
      },

    ],

    elements: {
      nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: 'n16'
        }
      }],
      edges: [{
        data: {
          source: 'n16',
          target: 'n16'
        },
        classes: 'loop'
      }, ]
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#cy {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.15.1/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <h1>cytoscape loop edge demo</h1>

  <div id="cy"></div>

</body>
```

You can find a reference for these values here:

https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-endpoints

Comment: Thanks!  Are you able to get that so it doesn't pass through the node at all?  i.e. push it to the far right so it goes around the outside of the node?

Comment: I'll check if using mentioned "unbundled bezier-edges" would be your initial desired solution. E.g. when you set manually control points for curves (edges).

Based on documentation and tests I believe that's the only way possible. It may take a while, I'm off to vacation.

Comment: thanks.  Looking again at the docs I havent tried `source-distance-from-node` either